# Access tuple in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
 t=[]
 t.append(("a",1))
 t.append(("b",2))
 t.append(("c",3))
 return render_to_response(t.html,  context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'t':t}))
```

How can I access a value of `t` in Django templates without using a `for` loop? I have tried the following and it doesn't seem to work:

```
    alert('{{t[a]}}');
    alert('{{t[c]}}');
```

Comment: Theres an error in your code assigning values to t. Currently it fails with TypeError, so we can't be sure what the *real* structure of t is, so we can't help you. Copy-Paste your view code to prevent these mistakes.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Assuming your view code is:

```
t=[]
t.extend([('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)])
```

(and not as stated in the OP)

`{{ t.0.0 }}` is like `t[0][0]` in Python code. This should give you "a", because `t.0` is the first element of the list t, which itself is a tuple, and then another `.0` is the tuple's first element.

`{{ t.0.1 }}` will be 1, and so on.

But in your question you are creating a tuple and trying to access it as if it is a dict.

That's the problem.

Comment: cant we access the values from the keys namely a,b,c??

Comment: You can, but you'll have to make t a dict: t = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, then t.a should work.

Answer (score 6):

You can convert your tuple to dict via [dict() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
mydict = dict(t)
```

And then in template you can access items by key like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable):

```
{{ mydict|get_item:item.NAME }}
```