# Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

```
mydict = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
```

The regular way to lookup a dictionary value in a Django template is `{{ mydict.key1 }}`,  `{{ mydict.key2 }}`. What if the key is a loop variable? ie:

```
{% for item in list %} # where item has an attribute NAME
  {{ mydict.item.NAME }} # I want to look up mydict[item.NAME]
{% endfor %}
```

`mydict.item.NAME` fails. How to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/2039467 return dictionary.get(key) if dictionary else return None

Answer (score 467, accepted):

Write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
...
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

(I use `.get` so that if the key is absent, it returns none. If you do `dictionary[key]` it will raise a `KeyError` then.)

usage:

```
{{ mydict|get_item:item.NAME }}
```

Comment: [Django Custom Template Tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags), for those finding this in the future.

Comment: Why is this not built in by default? :-(

Comment: I think @Jeff meant [Django Custom Template Filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

Comment: in Jinja2 {{ mydict[key] }}

Comment: Great solution. @BerislavLopac Sadly it's a wontfix with Django core developers : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3371

Comment: Does the filter go in views.py, some extra filters.py, or what file?

Comment: Is there a possibility to save the tag result in a variable?

Comment: +alanse I added it as a sub-function INSIDE the views.py function in question... but see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I mean in terms of the conceptual design of JSX for rendering HTML content as compared to Django templates.  There's no reason something much more React-like isn't possible in Python.

Comment: I was only able to get this to work after adding a name argument based on @Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita answer:

@register.filter(name='get_item')

Comment: @BerislavLopac because the Django template language sucked when it was created and it still sucks today. Friends don't let friends use Django templates.

Comment: @MatheusJardimB Is it possible to assign the return data of tag filter to a variable or to check the return data is not empty.
like,
variable={{ mydict|get_item:item.NAME }}

Comment: This worked for me.  How would I pass two arguments in this way?  {{ mydict_get_item:'attribute', 'second_attribute' }} does not seem to work.

Answer (score 95):

Fetch both the key and the value from the dictionary in the loop:

```
{% for key, value in mydict.items %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

I find this easier to read and it avoids the need for special coding. I usually need the key and the value inside the loop anyway.

Comment: He did not ask to enumerate a dict (as you show) - he asked to get the dict's value given a variable key.  Your proposal does not provide solution.

Comment: It is a solution (just very inefficient) since you can enumerate the items of the dict and then match with the key from the list.

Comment: Note that this does not work if the dictionary you are trying to access contains another dictionary inside.

Comment: If your values are dicts, you can include another for loop to process their keys and values but is likely that the complexity is taking you towards it being worth using a custom filter as described in @culebron's answer.

Comment: @PaulWhipp  i have the same problem but the key has multi values and when im tring your answer it shows only first value .

Comment: @M.Mevlevi I'm not sure what you mean by a key having multi values but I'm guessing that you have something like a dict with {a: [1, 2, 3]}. value would be bound to [1, 2, 3] in that case so you'd need to handle that appropriately rather than just presenting the value directly (which assumes it has a string representation).

Comment: I think this solution is still good for someone although it can't work if the value is another dictionary.

Answer (score 50):

You can't by default. The dot is the separator / trigger for attribute lookup / key lookup / slice.

> Dots have a special meaning in template rendering. A dot in a variable
>   name signifies a lookup. Specifically, when the template system
>   encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups,
>   in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup. Example: foo["bar"]
> - Attribute lookup. Example: foo.bar
> - List-index lookup. Example: foo[bar]

But you can make a filter which lets you pass in an argument:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

```
@register.filter(name='lookup')
def lookup(value, arg):
    return value[arg]

{{ mydict|lookup:item.name }}
```

Comment: I would still use `return value.get(arg)` because that would not throw a KeyError exception if the key is not present.

Comment: return value.get(arg, None)

Answer (score 8):

For me creating a python file named `template_filters.py` in my App with below content did the job

```
# coding=utf-8
from django.template.base import Library

register = Library()


@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

usage is like what culebrón said :

```
{{ mydict|get_item:item.NAME }}
```

Comment: Why `register = Library()` ? What does it do ?

Comment: If you want all your templates to know about your new filter, then you have to register it under `django.template.base.Library` class. by `register = Library()` we instantiate that class and use `filter` function annotator inside it to reach our need.

Answer (score 3):

Environment: Django 2.2

1. Example code:

```
    from django.template.defaulttags import register

    @register.filter(name='lookup')
    def lookup(value, arg):
        return value.get(arg)
```

I put this code in a file named template_filters.py in my project folder named portfoliomgr

2. No matter where you put your filter code, make sure you have **__init__.py** in that folder
3. Add that file to libraries section in templates section in your projectfolder/settings.py file. For me, it is portfoliomgr/settings.py

```
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
                'libraries':{
                    'template_filters': 'portfoliomgr.template_filters',
                }
            },
        },
    ]
```

4. In your html code load the library

   ```
   {% load template_filters %}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. However I used a different solution.

In my model I create a property that does the dictionary lookup. In the template I then use the property.

In my model: -

```
@property
def state_(self):
    """ Return the text of the state rather than an integer """
    return self.STATE[self.state]
```

In my template: -

```
The state is: {{ item.state_ }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, let me do this in the form of an answer:
to build on [culebrón's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/9171260) or [Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000078/9171260), the dictionary passed into the function is in the form of a string, so perhaps use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the string to a dictionary first, like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988251/9171260).

With this edit, the code should look like this:

```py
# code for custom template tag
@register.filter(name='lookup')
def lookup(value, arg):
    value_dict = ast.literal_eval(value)
    return value_dict.get(arg)
```

```html
<!--template tag (in the template)-->
{{ mydict|lookup:item.name }}
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign the value returned({{ mydict|lookup:item.name }}) to a variable

Comment: @Jibin I am not sure what you mean by your question. Perhaps my code was confusing; I have corrected it and added comments since then.

Comment: @Jibin coming from grails/gsp and other template languages I had the same question - but one needs to think different in django: you can do that _before_ you render the template. When you create the context for the template in the view you can just add transient properties and (I believe) even methods to your model objects and access those from the template - great for all adhoc stuff you need just in that template and gives very readable template code.

Answer (score 1):

Please *don't*. Arbitrary dictionary lookups have not been implemented by Django, but for *good* reasons.

The main reason not to do this, is that logic in the template that needs this, is often *business logic*. Such logic does *not* belong to the template, but should be moved to the view.

Another problem is that Django's template engine is not very efficient: it requires a lot of context resolutions, and rendering logic, meaning that such dictionary lookups are thus not "for free", these will slow down rendering, especially if it is done in a loop.

Often it will also require resolving the variable that is the key, and this can make debugging more *tricky*, since it is possible that the result of the context resolution is not what one would expect. For example if the variable is not found, it will use the [**`string_if_invalid`** value <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/language/#variables), which is not per se what one might intend, and thus the behavior could produce a result, but a wrong result.

Finally if an error occurs, it makes debugging harder, and if something goes wrong, it is possible that this is passed *silently*, whereas it is often better that in case something fails, it is at least logged somewhere.

If you need to perform arbitrary *subscripting* or attribute lookups, that means you should move the logic from the template to the *view*. Indeed, in that case you prepare the data in the view, for example here with:

```
def my_view(request):
    my_list = ['key2']
    my_dict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
    result = [my_dict[k] for k in my_list]
    return render(request, 'name-of-template.html', {'result': result})
```

and thus then process `result` in the template, not the logic with *`my_dict`* and *`my_list`*.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works fine, but I just want to add how to drill down nested value using filter chaining

```
mydict = {"USD": { "amount": 30 }, "JPY": { "amount": 3000 }}
```

```
currency = "JPY"
{{ mydict|get_item:currency|get_item:"amount" }}
```

The output will be `3000`

Answer (score 0):

After the 11 years later.

You can use this doc for 4.2 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

views.py

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import register
@register.simple_tag
def example_tag(var_1, var_2, *args, **kwargs):
    args_1 = kwargs["args_1"]
    args_2 = kwargs["args_2"]

    return args_1+" "+ args_2
```

example.html

```
{% example_tag variable_1 variable_2 args_1="hi" args_2="hello" %}
```

output

```
hi hello
```

Answer (score -2):

env: django 2.1.7

view:

```
dict_objs[query_obj.id] = {'obj': query_obj, 'tag': str_tag}
return render(request, 'obj.html', {'dict_objs': dict_objs})
```

template:

```
{% for obj_id,dict_obj in dict_objs.items %}
<td>{{ dict_obj.obj.obj_name }}</td>
<td style="display:none">{{ obj_id }}</td>
<td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
<td>{{ dict_obj.obj.update_timestamp|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s"}}</td>
```

Comment: The template code `{{ dict_obj.obj.obj_name }}` is in this case equivalent to Python code `dict_obj["obj"]["obj_name"]`, however, the question is about the equivalent of `dict_obj[obj][obj_name]`.

Comment: How is the answer used, inside a template?