# Django template: Looping through query_set and dictionary at the same time (or combining them)?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

If I have a queryset called Fruit, whose model is something like:

```
class Fruit(model.Models)
    name = models.CharField()
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Producer)
```

In my view, I have a dynamically created dictionary, called Fruit_Quality, which contains something like `{'Orange' : 'ripe', 'Apple' : 'overripe', etc.}`

I want to be able to pass both the query_set and the dictionary to the template, and loop through the query_set instances, to output lines that looks like:

```
{{ Fruit.name Fruit.producer.name Fruit.producer.location Fruit_Quality[Fruit.name] }}
```

The latter syntax to reference the fruit in the dictionary, is of course not a valid template syntax.  Is there a valid syntax?  I can't find any.

If there is no valid syntax, is there a way to loop through the query_set and dictionary, at the same time?

Note: Unfortunately I can't add the field "Fruit_Quality" to the model, because Fruit_Quality is dynamically created, and not meant to be stored.  So that is not a solution.

Also, I would like to have Fruit passed to the template as a queryset, so that I can reference the fields of foreign keys in the model, such as the producer.  If I didn't have that restriction, one could convert the queryset to a list of dictionaries in the view, and append Fruit_Qualtiy to each dictionary.  But those foreign keys prevents me from easily converting the queryset to a dictionary (without adding all the foreign key fields to the dictionary also).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Add property dynamically to model itself instead create alone dictionary: `fruit = Fruit.objects.get( pk = 3 )`; `fruit.quality = "ripe"` . Added property will be available in template.

Comment: Also, you can create a custom filter:  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3371

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable

Comment: "Unfortunately I can't add the field "Fruit_Quality" to the model, because Fruit_Quality is dynamically created, and not meant to be stored. So that is not a solution." try it, not in model definition but in view side.

Comment: I used the custom filter method, work very nicely.  I wish the django template language was as flexible as python.  I can understand their philosophy, but imagine how many man hours people have spent trying to do things that can't be done, and the effort people made to add custom filters. :)