# how to get argument in dictionary in django template?

Tags: django, templates, url

i need to pass from view to view using Balise  in django template, so i have a dictionary contained my arguments
this the code i used in my template

```
{% for item in data % }
{% for key, value in item.items %}

{% if key == '13' %}<a href="{% url hisaccount value %}">{% endif %}<p>go to view</p></a>

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but i get this error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /filter/

Reverse for '' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: How is `hisaccount` defined in `urls.py` ? If it is django 1.5, you might have to do `'hisaccount'`

Comment: url(r'^hisaccount/(?P<userid>[-\w]+)/$','Our_MarketPlace.views.his_account', name='hisaccount'),

Comment: which version of django ?

Comment: The problem is `{% url hisaccount ` is not resolving successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar.  After some digging, it looks like its not built in as a default Django template tag.

You need to build your own, I used this one that I've found on stackoverflow: [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

Comment: that is not the problem. His URL is not resolving properly. The dict is being evaluated correctly