# Django object_name rendering in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I've seen a SO post on this but can't seem to find it.

My results are rendering in my template with the object_name as 

`{'sessions__sum': 29649}`

instead of just 

`29649`.

How can I show just the sum?  Thank you.

**Update**

I realize, out of lack of knowledge, I may not have asked my question correctly, so below is my view and a screenshot of my template, rendered in the browser.  Hopefully this will help clear things up.

**view**

```
year_weekly_filter.filter(created__week_day=1).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))
monday2014 = year_weekly_filter.filter(created__week_day=2).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))
```

Template

```
{{ monday2014 }}
```

**ScreenShot - how its rendering in the browser**

[image]

Comment: If you're going to down vote, then you should provide some professional and useful feedback.  If not for me, at least for other users that may see this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that: "aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked, **returns a dictionary** of name-value pairs." - Django Docs
If you just want a single value to be returned to a variable and not a dict, use .get like so:

```
monday2014 = year_weekly_filter.filter(created__week_day=2).aggregate(Sum('sessions')).get('sessions__sum',0)
```

Comment: I have been banging my head for a day trying to figure this out...just didn't know how to ask the question.  Thank you!!!

Comment: No problem! I came across this recently in my own work and was baffled by it for a bit, makes sense to return a dict for creating multiple aggregations in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `{{object}}` in the template is rendered by the dictionary object?
In this case, the key is accessed in this way.

```
{{object.sessions__sum}}
```

and you may get help in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745091/accessing-dictionary-by-key-in-django-template) and the related documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups).

I don't have enough points to add a comment, so I leave my guess here.