# Django dict key,value in for loop does not work

Tags: python, django, dictionary, key

I'm getting a little stuck on a Django problem where I can't access the values of a dict in a for loop. It works outside the for loop, just not inside.

Am I missing the obvious here?

Python:

```
err{}
err['else'] = {'class': 'Low', 'txt': 'zero'}
err['if'] = {'class': 'High', 'txt': 'one'}
data = { 'errors': err }
return render(request, 'index/error.html', data)
```

HTML template:

```
<p>{{ errors }}</p>
<p>{{ errors.if }}</p>
<p>{{ errors.if.class }}</p>

{% for error in errors %}
  <div class="{{ error.class }}"><p>{{ error.txt }}</p></div>
{% endfor %}
```

The upper 3 lines are for code debugging and work just fine.
The for loop doesn't produce any code.

Best regards,
LVX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to access `.items()` of the `dict` that you called `errors`. Just iterating over a `dict` gives you the keys, but not the values.

You can change your code to:

```
{% for k, v in errors.items %}
  <div class="{{ v.class }}"><p>{{ v.txt }}</p></div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Of course, if you don't need the keys (`if` and `else`) then you could also use `.values()` instead of `items()` to just get the values inside the `dict`.

Comment: Thanks Ralf, that did the trick. I find it an odd way, but if you look at the code it somehow makes sense.

Comment: Can you please provide an example where do not know the key information eg: class or txt?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Ralf is sufficient for the question, I just want to add an extra piece of information here.

When the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following look-ups, in this order:

1. Dictionary Lookup (eg: foo['bar'])
2. Attribute Lookup (eg: foo.bar)
3. Method Call (eg: foo.bar())
4. List-Index Lookup (eg: foo[2])

The system uses the first lookup type that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this -
error['class']

Second way -
error[key]['class']

Use forloop -
for k,v in errors:
    print(v['class'])

Comment: Rohit: to my understanding of Django that is not allowed. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RohitGarg you cannot use brackets for access in `Django` templates. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19745156/9225671)