# Django display list of dictionary in template - dict key is a 'variable'

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am using Django 4.0  to display a frontend page which source data is a list of dict.
I want to order the keys of the dict and then display all dict in the list in the same order.
Here is my views.py:

```
def UserGoalstatus(request, promise_token):
    print("__UserGoalstatus__")
    from cmd_utils import Retrieve_goal
    data = Retrieve_goal(promise_token)
    keys = set()
    for item in data:
        keys.update(set(item))  
    key_order = sorted(keys)  

context = {
    "data": data,
    "key_order": key_order,
}
return render(request, 'json_table.html', context)
```

Here is the content of my 'data' variable:

```
[
{'goal_key': '286815', 'goal_type': 'hotelreservation', 'goal_id': 16149845, 'promise_token': '9ba51cbc-830b-64d603904099', 'campaign_id': 1002204, 'properties': {'price': 100, 'created': '2022-06-13 10:48:34', 'checkout': '2022-06-13', 'currency_code': 'USD', 'completed_booking_status': 1}}, 
{'goal_key': '1208107', 'goal_type': 'hotelreservation', 'goal_id': 16149846, 'promise_token': '9ba51cbc-830b-64d603904099', 'campaign_id': 1002204, 'properties': {'price': 100, 'created': '2022-06-13 10:48:35', 'checkout': '2022-06-13', 'currency_code': 'USD', 'completed_booking_status': 1}}
]
```

Here is my html file which I would like to print all content in data in the order of 'key_order'

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for key in key_order %}
            <th>{{ key }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in data %}
        <tr>
            {% for key in key_order %}
            <td>{{ item.get(key) }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This part seems not right :**{{ item.get(key) }}** , anyone can suggest the right way to access the value mapping to the specific **key** ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19745156/14169295) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

I need to define a django template filter of my own

The key part is 'get_item' , it can parse dictionary key as 'variable' in Django html now .
For more detailed information refer to links below:

[Django guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/4568140)

views.py

```
# customized template for html
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

in json_table.html

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for key in key_order %}
            <th>{{ key }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in data %}
        <tr>
            {% for key in key_order %}
            <td>{{ item | get_item:key}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```