# "bar" in a Django template expression is a literal?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Reading the Django doc

> Note that “bar” in a template expression like {{ foo.bar }} will be interpreted as a literal string and not using the value of the variable “bar”, if one exists in the template context

Does that mean that "bar" is some special keyword? Or that a variable called 'bar'(not belonging to object foo) can not be accessed like above?

I know I am missing something simple here, but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables can not be used in the dot notation after the `.`. Everything after the dot is interpreted as a string.

For example, if you have a `bar` variable and `foo` passed in a template context. `foo` is a dictionary `{'hello': 'world'}`, `bar` is a string `hello`.

`foo.bar` in this case won't return `world` since it will be evaluated to `foo['bar']`.

Demo:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> t = Template("{{ foo.bar }}")
>>> c = Context({'foo': {'hello': 'world'}, 'bar': 'hello'})
>>> t.render(c)
u''
```

What if `foo` has a key `bar`:

```
>>> c = Context({'foo': {'bar': 'world'}, 'bar': 'hello'})
>>> t.render(c)
u'world'
```

Hope this makes things clear to you.

Comment: (Since I don't know anything about Django) Is this true for all variables, or is `bar` special? Is `foo.baz == foo['baz']`?

Comment: @AdamSmith true for all variables. Should have mentioned it, sorry.

Comment: @AdamSmith I've clarified answer a bit, check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much @alecxe! So is there a way to get that functionality? i.e. Have bar = 'hello' and get 'world' from {'hello': 'world'}. Or is that some logic best left to the view than handled at the template?

Comment: @PavanKMutt sure, use custom template filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable