# Django template lists not iterable?

Tags: django, list, templates

Running into a strange problem with Django's template, and being n00b I don't even know how to debug a template...

PROBLEM: variables of a type `list` somehow stopped being a `list` when passed into the template.

In my view, I have a bunch of variables passed to the template that are a dictionary of lists. Here's the code,

**VIEW**

```
project_image_design = {}

for p in projects:    
    project_image_design[p.id] = []    
    images = UploadedImage.objects.filter(project=p, image_type=UploadedImage.DESIGN)

    for i in images:
        project_image_design[p.id].append(i)
```

Here's the context. I have projects, each contains images. I created a dictionary, where the keys are the project id, and the value is a list of images associated with that project.

However, when I use this in the template, things go wrong,

**TEMPLATE**

```
{% for p in projects %}
    <div class="row">

        {% for list in project_image_design|get_item:p.id %}
            {% for i in list %} 
                <div class="col-md-2"><img src = "{% get_static_prefix %}media/{{ i.filename }}"></div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So in the template, I'm iterating through projects, then using the project's id (`p.id`) to get the dictionary value, which is a list of images, and then iterating through that. The fancy `get_item` tag is just a way to access dictionary values through keys that not straight-forward variables (see: [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)).

Anyway, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /designer/my_projects/
'UploadedImage' object is not iterable
```

The error occurs on this line: `{% for i in list %}`, which is the line where I'm iterating through the list of images I retrieved using my project's id.

What's going on here????

I double-checked via pdb in the view, it all checks out. The variable being passed is indeed a dictionary of lists, I put a `type` on all the individual dictionary elements and they're all lists (like: `type(project_image_design[1])` would return `<class 'list'>`).

Also, at the moment, all the lists are of length 1. I'm wondering maybe the template sort of deflates lists that are size 1? That'd seem like a pretty weird thing to do, probably not the reason.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, how do I debug templates the way I can debug Python code? Like stepping through and stuff? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It hasn't stopped being a list. But you have two nested for loops: you iterate through the items you get from the dictionary - confusingly calling each item `list` - and then attempt to iterate again through items in that "list". But the inner loop makes no sense: you should be doing simply:

```
{% for i in project_image_design|get_item:p.id %}
    <div class="col-md-2"><img src = "{% get_static_prefix %}media/{{ i.filename }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd also point out that your view logic is over-complicated. It could be reduced to simply this:

```
for p in projects:    
    project_image_design[p.id] = UploadedImage.objects.filter(project=p, image_type=UploadedImage.DESIGN)
```

And in fact it could be simplified even further: you don't need the dictionary, or the get_item tag, at all. Instead, provide a method on Project called something like `design_images` which just returns the images of that type:

```
def design_images(self):
    return self.uploadedimage_set.filter(image_type=UploadedImage.DESIGN)
```

and removing the dictionary logic from the view altogether, and now your template can just be:

```
{% for p in projects %}
    <div class="row">

        {% for i in p.design_images %}
            <div class="col-md-2"><img src = "{% get_static_prefix %}media/{{ i.filename }}"></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```