# Using element of list as the key of dict in Django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I meet some problem while I try to use the element of list as the key of dict in Django.

My code is below:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}

{% for element in list %}
  {% for key, value in dict %}
    {{ value.element }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The question is that there is no key named `element` in dict, so it won't show the correct value.
The correct result should be `1`, `2`, `3`.

How can I use element of list as the key of dict instead of using the specific key in Django.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you should never call your lists list and your dict's dict

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable

Comment: actually, it's just a example...

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable). The solution uses a template filter.

Another way to achieve what you want is to use a condition on the value of key:

```
{% for element in list %}
  {% for key, value in dict %}
    {% if key == element %}{{ value.element }}{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what's the difference with and without the if condition?

Comment: I am not sure what you really want to achieve. The example I gave will print '123'. Without the if condition, it would print three times the dictionary values: '123123123' (or in another order, since dict objets are not ordered in Python). If you just want to get the value of the key 'a', remove the loop over the elements in list and replace "element" by "'a'" in my example.