# Jinja2 dictonary lookup using a variable key

Tags: python, jinja2

Using `Jinja2` how can I lookup the value in a dictionary where the key is a variable from a `Jinja2` for loop.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do

```
{% for field in fields %}
<td> {{ item[field] }} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Django, yes, this is [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable), but not for jinja2. The code you've provided works:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> env = jinja2.Environment()
>>> t = env.from_string("""
... {% for field in fields %}
... <td> {{ item[field] }} </td>
... {% endfor %}""")
>>> print t.generate(item={'key':'value'}, fields=['key']).next()
<td> value </td>
```

Comment: any chances I can use the same within {% if %} statements?