# Access template passed variables in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I pass to the template:

**testruns**, which is `"get_list_or_404(TestRun)"`

and

**dict**, which is smth like this:

```
for testrun in testruns:
    dict[testrun.id] = {
        'passed' : bla bla,
        'failed' : bla bla 2
    }
```

Practically a map between `testrun.id` and some other info from a set from **TestRun** Model

In the template I want to do this:

```
{% for testrun in testruns %}

     console.log("{{ dict.testrun.id }}");
{% endfor %}
```

But doesn't output anything

---

`console.log("{{ testrun.id }}");` will output a specific id ("37" for example)

`console.log("{{ dict.37 }}");` will output the corresponding value from the dict

So, why doesn't this output anything?

```
console.log("{{ dict.testrun.id }}");
```

How should I get the data from `'passed'` and `'failed'` from the **dict**:

Also, this:

```
console.log("{{ dict[testrun.id] }}");
```

Will output this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /path/dashboard

Could not parse the remainder: '[testrun.id]' from 'dict[testrun.id]'
```

Comment: why are you using `dict` as variable, ? confusing man....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot will be considered as a trigger for attribute lookup by template engine, so `dict.testrun.id` will be parsed as "try to find `id` attribute from `testrun` attribute from `dict`". Instead, if you want to show the whole dict content, you might just iterate through dictionary:

```
{% for key, value in dict.items %}
    Testcase: {{ key }}
    Passed: {{ value.passed }}
    Failed: {{ value.failed }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you are looking for dict lookup by variable's value, you will have to make custom template tag, like it was described here - [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)