# Accessing a dictionary in a template - a value is empty

Tags: python, django

This prints, when the key `k` exists in `key2`, a empty link, meaning its href is empty. The real **value** of `k` in `key2` isn't empty.

```
# data is a dictionary
{% for k, v in data.key1.items %}
  {% if k in data.key2 %}
    <h3><a href='{{data.key2.k}}'>{{k}}</a></h3> <!-- this generates <a href>fdsfdsd</a> -->
  {% else %}
    <h3>{{ k }}</h3>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. are you saying "k is in data.key2, but when you write {{ data.key2.k }}, it does not print anything?"

Comment: `k` is among keys in `key2` dictionary, but id doesn't mean, that `key2[k]` is not an empty string.

Comment: @Alik, its value isn't.

Comment: @jawanam how do you check that?

Comment: Is data.key2 also a dictionary?

Comment: @Alik, {% if k in data.key2 %}  {{data.key2}}

Comment: if data is a dictionary, then `for k, v in data.items` should be used instead of `data.key1.items`

Comment: @Alik sometimes `k` consists  of 2 words, but not always.

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{{data.key2.k}} is accessing the key 'k' in data.key2 which is probably not what you intended.
There is now way to do dictionary lookups by a variable in django templates.

One solution would be a custom template filter like suggested here:
[Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)