# Dictionary in Django template - filter usage

Tags: python, django, dictionary

i have a view that returns a dict. I searched around SO and found : [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-lookup-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

this is the return statement of my view:

```
return render(request, 'App/index.html', context={'talks': word_count})
```

I´m pretty new in django so i think this is why i do not notice the error here. The answer to the mentioned question is this one, create a filter and load it in the template, ok, this is the filter:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

And here is where i am using it in the wrong way:

```
<ul>
    {% for talk in talks %}
        <li>{{  talks|get_item:talk.count  }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is the dictionary i have:

```
{' - Nacho:': 1211, ' - Pato:': 1950, ' - Nicolas:': 1871, '}
```

the way i created it is this one:

```
lista = {}
for line in lines:
            if user in line:
                count += 1
lista[user] = count
```

simple as that. The error i´m having is this one:

```
All the elements appear like this:

. None
. None
. None
```

not knowing exactly how to use the filter is making it hard to fix this
Maybe someone with more experience in django can point me in the right direction

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary items do not have a `count` attribute.

But I don't know why you think you need this filter at all. You have a simple dictionary, not a complex nested data structure; if you simply want the key (name) and value (count) for each element, just iterate through with `items`:

```
{% for name, count in talks.items() %}
    <li>{{ name }} - {{ count }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect, i just deleted the "()" and this worked. Thanks