# How to read a dash in html from django context

Tags: python, json, django, html

I have a json that looks like this

```
{    
        "values": {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
            "c": 3,
            "d": 4
        },
    "sales-year": [
        { "a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": "karl" },
        { "a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": "karl" },
        { "a": 4, "b": 10, "c": 20, "d": 30, "e": "karl" },
        { "a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 0, "e": "karl" }
    ]
}
```

And I pass it through `get_context_data` with django to my 'index.html'. Further explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049850/how-to-parse-a-json-file-from-context-data-with-html-in-django/34050159#34050159)

I  can access the values pretty easy with `{{my_json.values.a}}` However I am having problems accessing the `sales-year` array. How do I do that? I tried the following, none of them work:

```
{{my_json['sales-this'].2.a}} 
{{my_json.['sales-this'].2.a}} 
{{my_json.[sales-this].2.a}} 
{{my_json[sales-this].2.a}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a custom template filter to handle this

First create a custom template filter like:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def getItem(dict, key):
    return dict.get(key)
```

next in your template do like:

```
{{my_json|getItem:'sales-year'}}
```

Learn more on how to use/create custom filters [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)