# How can I get first value in a dictionary in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

```
a = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'...}
```

This dictionary is being sent to my django template.
How can I get `value1`?

Note: I don't know `key1`, as it is dynamically generated.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered, so there isn't a 'first' value. You can get all the values in a list with `a.values`, or get the first of this list (not necessarily `value1`) with `a.values.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#first) filter with [dict.values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) method:

```
{{ a.values|first }}
```

But remember: dict is unordered. Of course You can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

For `OrderedDict`  use [make_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#make_list) filter :

```
{{ a.values|make_list|first }}
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you used make_list.. But it worked without that...   {{ a.values | first }}

Comment: Django is smarter than I thought. `dict.values` return a `dict_values` class object that does not support indexing. Fixed.

Comment: `first` does not work for me on an `OrderedDict`. Returns a `TypeError` `odict_values' object does not support indexing`?

Comment: @Anupam use `make_list` filter first

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup yeah I had picked that up from the edit history and did try it earlier :) That didnt work either. It strangely converted everything into a list of characters `['o', 'd', 'i', 'c', 't', '_', 'v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e', 's', '(', '[', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ']', ')']` So `first` returned `o`

Comment: FYI: I just ended up creating a template tag to lookup the first value using the key like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/1526703) (I do know the key beforehand - unlike OP's case)