# iterate list and use that value for dictionary key

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-templates

My dictionary looks some think like this.

```
allCurrencies = {
    'AUD': ['Australian Dollar', 'au'],
    'GBP': ['British Pound', 'gb'],
    'CAD': ['Canadian Dollar', 'ca'],
    'INR': ['Indian Rupee', 'in'],
    'JPY': ['Japanese Yen', 'jp'],
    'RUB': ['Russian Ruble', 'ru'],
    'SGD': ['Singapore Dollar', 'sg'],
    'CHF': ['Swiss Franc', 'ch'],
    'USD': ['US Dollar', 'us']
}
```

and my array contains this:

```
commonCurrencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY']
```

My main goal is to iterate commonCurrencies and use it as a key for the dictionary allCurrencies.

My django template currently look like this:

```
<tr>
    {% for sym in commonCurrencies %}
        <td>{{allCurrencies.sym.0}}<td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

But it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/4974980)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no builtin filter, tag that allow you to get item from dictionary dynamically. You'd better filter the value in views, and pass it to template. [Otherwise, you need to make custom template tag to get value dictionary value dynamically.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/2225682)

```
>>> allCurrencies = {
...     'AUD': ['Australian Dollar', 'au'],
...     'GBP': ['British Pound', 'gb'],
...     'CAD': ['Canadian Dollar', 'ca'],
...     'INR': ['Indian Rupee', 'in'],
...     'JPY': ['Japanese Yen', 'jp'],
...     'RUB': ['Russian Ruble', 'ru'],
...     'SGD': ['Singapore Dollar', 'sg'],
...     'CHF': ['Swiss Franc', 'ch'],
...     'USD': ['US Dollar', 'us']
... }
>>>
>>> commonCurrencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY']
>>>
>>> currencies = {cur: allCurrencies[cur] for cur in commonCurrencies
                  if cur in allCurrencies}
>>>
>>> currencies
{'JPY': ['Japanese Yen', 'jp'],
 'USD': ['US Dollar', 'us'],
 'GBP': ['British Pound', 'gb']}
```

BTW, there's no `EUR` entry in the `allCurrencies` dictionary.

Comment: awesome thanks a lot