# Django template cannot access JSON Key in duplicate quotations: {" 'Key' ": " Value "}

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

My Django app is interacting with an API and displaying results in the templates.

The API result has some normal Key Value pairs and some custom fields which have a Key in double and single quotations.

The key is formatted as " 'custom_field_123' " in the result JSON:

```
{'cost_price': '0.00', "'asset_field_1234'": None, "'asset_field_5768'": None}
```

I know this isn't correct JSON format but it's what I have to deal with.

In the Django templates I can use:

```
<p>{{tower.name}}</p>
```

for regular format keys.
But the template language will not recognize:

```
<p>{{tower.'custom_field_123'}}</p>
```

Or

```
<p>{{tower.('custom_field_123')}}</p>
```

Is there a way to access these values or will I have to rename the keys in quotations to access them in the template.

Comment: You should fix whatever is generating that JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the template reference docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/):

> Variable names must consist of any letter (A-Z), any digit (0-9), an underscore (but they must not start with an underscore) or a dot.

So quotes aren't allowed, and the template language has no way to directly access those properties.

You could write your own template tag to look up dictionary items by a variable key (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)) but I would suggest fixing your data.

Comment: Yeah suspected this would be the answer, Unfortunately the data is coming from another service, Thanks.