# django - Use loop variables as a dictionary key

Tags: python, html, django, templates, dictionary

I have some issues with access of a specific key in my template. Here is my code :

```
{% for rsim,couples in zipped_formated_rxnsim_pairedsim %}
    -{{rsim.xxx_fk.xxx_code_char}} #ex : toto
    {% for rsim2,couples2 in mydict.{{rsim.xxx_fk.xxx_code_char}}%}
        <li> {{rsim2}} - {{couples2}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It gives me this error,

> Could not parse the remainder: '{{rsim.xxx_fk.xxx_code_char}}' from 'mydict.{{rsim.xxx_fk.xxx_code_char}}'

I do not understand this behaviour, because if I hard code the line `{% for rsim2,couples2 in mydict.{{rsim.pdb_fk.pdb_code_char}}%}` to `{% for rsim2,couples2 in mydict.toto %}` it works ... I mean, how can I do something about this idea ?

I really need this loop structure, because I want to go through "*rsim2,couples2*" tuples only for a specific "*rsim,couple*" tuple. In others words, "*rsim2,couples2*", are extra data linked with  "*rsim,couples*". What a better solution than a dictionary using a key ?

I tried using the {{with}} tag, adding a variable to use directly as a key, but it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: What's not to understand? You can't use `{{ }}` variable syntax when you're already inside a template tag.

Comment: By not understanding, I meant, how can I do something similar. Thank you @DanielRoseman

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

Comment: @MateuszKnapczyk I saw it before asked my question, I wanted others ( better ? ) solutions rather write a custom template filter. You can see that others answers about your link do not answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General answers are

1. Add a helper method to accomplish what you want in Python rather than template language. This is usually recommended if in one's template, `thingy.something` refers to a Django model instance. Here, it doesn't appear to.
2. Write your own template tag or filter, or search for an appropriate one that someone else has already written. Writing a template tag such as this is actually quite easy -- just follow the example in the Django doc. [edit] See the link posted in the question's comments.
3. Use a different template language to the Django built-in one. Django now supports Jinja2. I don't know if that can do what you want, and have no experience with using it. It's probably using a sledgehammer to crack a nut if the above is the only problem you have with Django's own template language.

Comment: I was looking for this kind of answer, perfect, I am going to check it. Thank you