# I am looking for a quick way to retrieve values from a dictionary in templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have the following situation:

```
{% if accounts.count > 0 %}
    {% for account in accounts %}
      <div>Balance:<b>{{ my_dict.account.id }}</b></div>
      <div><a href="/edit/{{ account.id }}"><button>Edit</button></a></div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>...</p>
{% endif %}
```

.

Such arrangement is ok

```
my_dict.account
```

But I'll do something like that. I have two dots

**`my_dict.account.id`**

Is there any way to do this? It would be a good idea to create a **variable in template** but it does not work for me

Comment: so what's `my_dict` holding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

Comment: I do not want to create my own filter. So this is not the same thing

Comment: My_dict has a dictionary. Key: value

Comment: it is, nested dict lookup in templates are a bit annoying at times. just scroll down to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31363412/4033315.

Comment: @Geotob How to connect a loop to a loop in this situation? I do not want to display everything as in this example in the link.

Comment: @programmerJavaPL please provide a sample `my_dict` to see the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to see your my_dict dictionary structure: what is key (is it account id?)

It can be something like this:

```
my_dict[account.id]
```

Though if my_dict somehow doesn't have the key, you'll encounter an error. So you might wanna do this instead:

```
my_dict.get(account.id, 'default value')
```

'default value' is what will be returned in case if there's no such key in my_dict.