# Invalid filter error in django custom template filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create a custom template filter but, getting `Invalid filter` error.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /attainment/reportcard/
Invalid filter: 'get_item'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/attainment/reportcard/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid filter: 'get_item'
Exception Location: /media/itsd/ITSD/ROFI/Projects/Rise/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py in find_filter, line 606
Python Executable:  /media/itsd/ITSD/ROFI/Projects/Rise/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

I've created a filter in `template_filters.py` and registered.

**template_filters.py**

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

# Custom template filter to get data from a dictionary using key in template

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

And I've used the filter in the template as follows.

```
<tbody>
    {% for subject in subjects %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ subject|get_item:"subject" }}</td>
            <td>{{ subject|get_item:"efffort" }}</td>
            <td>{{ subject|get_item:"homework" }}</td>
            <td>{{ subject|get_item:"marks" }}</td>
            <td>{{ subject|get_item:"grade" }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

What am I missing ??

N.B: I've followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/3968623).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the tag library before you use it in the template:

```
{% load template_filters %}
```

Or you can load the specific filter:

```
{% load get_item from template_filters %}
```

See the docs on [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) and the [`{% load %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#load) tag for more info.

Comment: It's showing `'template_filters' is not a registered tag library.`

Comment: It worked after I've created a directory named `templatetags` in my app and moved `template_filters.py` in that directory. Also I had to create a `__init__.py`  in that directory.

Comment: Those steps are all covered by the [code layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) section of the docs that I linked to.