# dictionary values can't be iterated through using their corresponding keys in django template

Tags: python, django-templates

So I have a nested dictionary in the form of the following:

```
data =  { server:{'rating':{'class':'good, 'desc':'whatever'}, 'vulnerabilities':{'heartbleed':{'severity':'critical', 'desc':'terrible config'}}
```

I want to iterate through the values using keys, I've read the documentations and this is what I do in template:

```
  {% for key, value in data.items %}
      <p> 'This is the key {{ key }} and this is the value {{value}}'<p>
  {% endfor %}
```

so far so good, the bizarre thing is that I can`t get the values using the key retrieved by the for loop, namely, when I have such a template:

```
  {% for key in data.keys %}]
       <p> 'This is the key: {{key}}' </p> 
       <p> 'This is the value: {{ data.key }}'<p>
  {% endfor %}
```

`{{key}}` returns the keys with no problem. Even when I do `{{data.server}}` I get the corresponding values with no problem. Strange thing is that this line `{{data.key}}` does not work as I intuit it to.

In one loop the `key==server`, `{{data.server}}` works but `{{data.key}}` does not. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Because your dictionary has no key called `'key'`? It does have a key `'server'`, which is why that one works. You will have to use the django equivalent of `data[key]`, instead of `data['key']`, which is what it is doing now.

Comment: @Graipher tnx, now I get it why it doesn't work. Does django have an equivalent for data[key]?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about django. But I'm sure there is a way.

Comment: I can't understand why you'd want to do this though, when iterating through `.items` works.

Comment: @DanielRoseman my actual dictionary is far more complicated than this. Each initial key has a {rating:rating} of its own which I want to use to style the corresponding container ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to this *dynamically* in template engine is to use [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

Take a look at [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable) for primer implementation