# How to access the dynamic key in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Please see the following the code:

```
{% for row in df_src.iterrows %}
   <tr >
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>                              
    {% for col in columns %}
      <td  class="redrow">{{row.1.col}}</td>                                  
    {% endfor %}                                                               
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here in `{{row.1.col}}` where `col` can be any value like `NAME`, `PHONE`, etc. When I access it like `{{row.1.PHONE}}` I get the value in html, however when I access it like `{{row.1.col}}` nothing is shown in html.

Comment: The second for loop seems wrong.
What's the structure of the  row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access it that way, djangos template language does not allow that. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable) that @BearBrown mentioned in his comment.

You could write your own [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)
like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/9225671) shows:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
...
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```