# How to parse JSON Array of objects in python and load it to template?

Tags: python, json, django, parsing, object

How can we parse json array of objects in python. I have the ff code below in getting the data. How to parse it where in we can load the p_id and item_name on the tempalte select option value ?

```
products = requests.get('http://123.89.166.42:803/api/1.0/data', headers=headers).json()
        context['products'] = products
```

template :

```
<select>
          {% for product in products.result %}
          <option value="{{ product.p_id }}">{{ product.item_name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

Data : http://dpaste.com/0BHS9TP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON does not have a top-level `result` key. It has a `response` key, which itself contains a `result`. So:

```
{% for product in products.response.result %}
```