# Accessing django template's dictionaries given a variable?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My question is if there's a way to obtain a value of a dictionary given a key. For example, imagine that `my_dictionary` is `{1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}`and I have an attribute which is `key` which equals 1. How can I obtain `'a'`? I tried with `{{my_dictionary.key}}`and `{{my_dictionary.{{key}} }}`but none of them worked. My idea is to do the same as with python, which is `my_dictionary[key]` but in a Django Template.

Thank you

Comment: Try to console.log this and show results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:

```
{% for key, values in data.items %}
   {% if key == 1 %}
      {{ value }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is to write a custom template filter:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
register = Library()
...
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    # use .get so that if the key does not exist a KeyError will be raised
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

usage in templates:

```
{{ data.items|get_item:<key_variable_here> }}
```