# Iterate and format dictionary returned by template filter

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm trying to display metadata about an image in my Django app. The metadata is read from the image's exif header and stored in a dictionary with the image as a key, and returned to the template with a filter. In my template, I display the images, and would like to display the formatted metadata for that image. So far I can only get it to display the dictionary for that image (e.g. `{'key1': 'value', 'key2', 'value'}`). I would like it to look like `key1: value, key2: value`.

```
#template.html
{% block content %}
    {% for image in images %}
        {{ exif|get_item:image }}
            <p><img src="{{ image.image.url }}" width="500" style="padding-bottom:50px"/></p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}


#views.py
def image_display(request):
    images = image.objects.all()

    exif = {}
    for file in images:
        cmd = 'exiftool ' + str(file.image.url) + ' -DateTimeOriginal -Artist'
        exifResults = (subprocess.check_output(cmd)).decode('utf8').strip('\r\n')
        exif[file] = dict(map(str.strip, re.split(':\s+', i)) for i in exifResults.strip().splitlines() if i.startswith(''))

    context = {
        'images': images,
        'exif': exif,
    }

    @register.filter
    def get_item(dictionary, key):
        return dictionary.get(key)
    return render(request, 'image_display.html', context=context)
```

I thought I could just do `{% for key, value in exif|get_item:image.items %}` in the template, but that returns an error:

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /reader/image_display
Failed lookup for key [items] in <image: image1>
```

Is there a way I can either format the dictionary returned by the filter or iterate through it such that I can format each key and value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you are using this question's custom filter implementation: [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable) but you need an extra step to format the specific key as it is a dictionary.

Why not create another filter that can return a dictionary formatted as you want?
Something like this:

```
@register.filter
def get_item_formatted(dictionary, key):
    tmp_dict = dictionary.get(key, None)
    if tmp_dict and isinstance(tmp_dict, dict):
        return [[t_key, t_value] for t_key, t_value in tmp_dict.items()]
    return None
```

This will return a list of lists of `[key, value]` pairs or `None`.
You can iterate through that in the template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for image in images %}
        {% for pair in exif|get_item_formatted:image %}
            // Do what you need with the pair.0 (key) and pair.1 (value) here. 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. Unfortunately I'm getting a syntax error: `return [[t_key: t_value] for t_key, t_value in tmp_dict.items]:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  (The arrow is pointing to the colon in `t_key:`)

Comment: Thanks! Now it's saying there's a syntax error at the lost colon -- `tmp_dict.items]:`. Tried without but got `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @Bird I did a sloppy job at writing this one. Sorry, have another go now that I edited the answer again.

Comment: Thanks for the update and help! Still getting the `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable` error. I think it's from `for t_key, t_value in tmp_dict.items`.  Tried just `return temp_dict.items` and same error.  Any idea why that would be?

Comment: I think I found it -- changing `tmp_dict.items` to `tmp_dict.items()` seems to make it work.

Comment: @Bird Yes that is true.