# Django Template Access a dictionary values with variable

Tags: django, python-3.x, loops, django-templates

I have a list with IP Addresses. I also have a nested dictionary which uses those addresses as keys. For example:

```
my_list = ['1.2.3.4', '8.8.8.8']

my_dic = {'data': {'1.2.3.4': 'My First Data', '8.8.8.8': 'My Second Data'}}
```

In my template I am trying to this:

```
for each in my_list:
    print(my_dic['data'][each])
```

Everything works well until I hit that `each` key. So if I just print `my_dic` or `my_dic[data]` it will all work correctly. But when I add the `each` index nothing shows up in the webpage

I have printed `each` independently so I know that it works correctly. 
This also works as expected when I run the loop in my IDE so I know the logic is right.

In django my code looks like this:

```
{% if my_dic.data %}
    {% for each in my_list %}
      <p>{{ my_dic.data.each }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I'm new to Django so not sure if I'm overlooking something silly. Anyone know what I am missing here?

**EDIT** 
Found a duplicate  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)  which covers my issue. Same issue Vishnu Ks pointed out.

Comment: First of all, your `my_dic` dict has some syntax error. Is that a typo?

Comment: Trying to iterate over a dictionary - let alone a nested one that you're accessing with variable keys - within a template is a bit of a pain with Django. This isn't an answer to your question, but I would strongly recommend considering performing this sort of logic within your view and then passing the processed list to your template for simpler and faster processing.

Comment: apart from that, you can't create/have a dict with same key (`data`)

Comment: It was a type in the dic, I fixed it

Comment: @JPJ   - the data lives in dictionary under data. There is only one data key there.

Comment: In the sample code your provided shouldn't it be `my_dic['data'][each]` instead of my_dic.data.each ?

Comment: @souldeux  Considering it works perfectly on the view side you may be right.

Comment: @VishnuKs  No in a django template it is '.' notated not brackets

Comment: @Joe Okay. In that case data.each will be equalent to data["each"] right and not data[each]? That explains why its not working.

Comment: No 100% sure, but when I print the `each` by itself it doesn't come with quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you try to access `data.each` Django will look for data["each"] and not data[each].Since there is no key named "each" in my_dic nothing would be printed.

If you want to access the value of data[each] inside the template you need to write a custom template filter.

```py
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

Then change the Django template code to this.

```
{% if my_dic.data %}
    {% for each in my_list %}
      <p>{{ my_dic.data|get_item:each }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

See [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-varia) for more details.

Comment: @Vishuks  I just found a similar answer to this that I think will work. Do I put this in my views.py?

Comment: Yup. You can put that in your views or create a separate file for keeping custom filters. Anything will work :)