# Django template language

Tags: django, django-templates

"dishList" is a list of "dish" object and "dish" object includes an "id" field. For example:

```
dishList = [dish1, dish2, dish3, ...]
dish1.id = 1
```

"dishCount" is a dictionary type in python, which include a number for each dish. For example:

```
dishCount = { dish1.id: 0, dish2.id: 0, ...}
```

My problem is that in this for loop:

`{% for d in dishList %}`

How can I assess the number of dish "d"?
I want to use `{{ dishCount.(d.id) }}` but it is not working.

Could not parse the remainder: '(d.id)' from 'dishCount.(d.id)'

Comment: The django templating language is designed to focus on the display, not on the logic. So it's not possible to fetch elements of a dictionary by a variable key. You could write a template filter that does that, but it's probably better if your view sends a different context to your template, where your list of dishes already has the counts.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I assess the number of dish "d"?

Django's template languages is *deliberately* restricted not to allow subscripting and function calls (with parameters). You strictly speaking *can* use a template filter for that, or use a template engine like [*jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/).

The reason why it is however restricted is more interesting: it aims to prevent users from writing *business logic* in the templates. It is usually better to write that in the view.

You thus can add an attribute to your dishes, like:

```
dishList = [dish1, dish2, dish3]
dishCount = { dish1.id: 0, dish2.id: 0}
for dish in dishList:
    dish.count = dishCount[dish.id]
```

Then you can render this with:

```
{% for d in dishList %}
    {{ d.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make custome template tag or you can use for loop in dict.items() in dict and get the item key and value

[Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

You can find out more here