# Check whether value in dict with for loop in Django's template

Tags: django, dictionary, for-loop, templates

I have the following data in my views.

```
months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
mydict = {3:'a',4:'b'}
```

The key means month,if this month exists value,then render the value,else leave blank.
Here's my template.

```
{% for j in months %}
    {% if mydict.j %}
        <th class="align-middle">{{ mydict.j }}</th>
    {% else %}
        <th class="align-middle"></th>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But the result always is blank.
I can access the value by `mydict.3`,but i can't get the value by `mydict.j` with a forloop.

Comment: By using `{{ mydict.j }}`, you try to perform a lookup `mydict['j']`. You can not perform a dictionary lookup in Django templates (unless making custom template filters etc.). This is done *on purpose*. This logic should be done in the *view* not in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write `{{ mydict.j }}`, then Django aims to lookup the value `mydict['j']`, not `mydict[j]`.

Dictionary lookups and function calls (with arguments) are *deliberately* not allowed in a template, such that developers are encouraged to write business logic in the *view* not in the template. You can write a [custom template filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8000022/67579), or make use of the [*jinja* template renderer to allow this](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/).

But it might be more sensical to do the mapping in the view:

```
def some_view(request):
    mydict = {3:'a',4:'b'}
    monthsanddict = [(x, mydict.get(x)) for x in range(1, 13)]
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'monthsanddict': monthsanddict})
```

and in the template, you can then render this with:

```
{% for j, mydictj in monthsanddict %}
    {% if mydictj %}
        <th class="align-middle">{{ mydictj }}</th>
    {% else %}
        <th class="align-middle"></th>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```