# Access object value by other object value in template in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates

This `{{ category.id }}`  returns me 1

This `{{ categories_counts.1 }}` returns me data

But `{{ categories_counts.category.id }}` doesn't work?

Is it possible to access value by other object value?

**views.py:**

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
categories_counts = {}
for category in categories:
    count = Venue.objects.filter(category_id=category.id).count()
    categories_counts[category.id] = count
```

So `categories` containst:

```
<QuerySet [<Category: restaurants>, <Category: sportfitness>, <Category: carservices>, <Category: beautysalons>]>
```

`categories_counts` contains:

```
{1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0}
```

**category Model:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bg_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)
    category_bg_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
```

Comment: You need a [custom template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

Comment: If you show your view and template, there might be another way you can loop through the dictionary, for example `{% for category, count in categories_counts.items %}{{ category }}{{ count }}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: I'm guessing `categories_counts` is a list and there's nothing at `categories_counts['category']` so that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alasdair it's udpated

Comment: @TimTisdall  It's updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't access `categories_counts[category.id]` in the Django template unless you create a custom template tag, as @sayse says in the comments.

In your specific case, you can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) the queryset with the venue counts.

```
from django.db.models import Count
categories = Category.objects.annotate(num_venues=Count('venue'))
```

Then in your template you can do something like:

```
{% for category in categories %}
{{ category.name }} has {{ category.num_venues }} venue(s)
{% endfor %}
```