# (Django python) Using multiple 'for loop' for render

Tags: python, html, django

Hey guys I'm making English test system for education by using Django python.
the system display one article and several(**not fixed**) questions about the article.
and every question has selectable items which **numbers are not fixed.**

for example
{ ---------- article -------------- }
{ ---------- question --------------}
{ ---------- item ------------------}
{ ---------- item ------------------}
{ ---------- item ------------------}
{ ---------- question --------------}
{ ---------- item ------------------}
{ ---------- item ------------------}
{ ---------- item ------------------}

so I defined model like this :

```
# Question DB
class Article(models.Model):
    a_name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    a_con = models.TextField() #Article Contents

class Question(models.Model):
    q_name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    q_a = models.ForeignKey(Article,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    q_con = models.TextField() #Question Contents
    q_ans = models.TextField() #Question Correct Answer
    
class Item(models.Model):
    i_q = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    i_seq = models.PositiveIntegerField() #Item Sequence
    i_con = models.TextField() #Item Contents

# Image DB
class ArticleImage(models.Model):
    ai_name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    ai_a = models.ForeignKey(Article,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ai_src = models.TextField()

class QuestionImage(models.Model):
    qi_name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    qi_q = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qi_src = models.TextField()

class ItemImage(models.Model):
    ii_name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    ii_i = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ii_src = models.TextField()
```

and I wrote view.py like this:

```
def findQuestionbyArticle(article_name):
    _ARTICLE_ = Article.objects.filter(a_name = article_name)
    for a in _ARTICLE_:
        _ARTICLE_IMAGE_ = ArticleImage.objects.filter(ai_a = a)
        _QUESTION_ = Question.objects.filter(q_a = a)
        _ITEM_ = {}
        _ITEM_IMAGE_ = {}
        for q in _QUESTION_:
            _QUESTION_IMAGE_ = QuestionImage.objects.filter(qi_q = q)
            _ITEM_[q] = Item.objects.filter(i_q = q)
            for i in _ITEM_[q]:
                _ITEM_IMAGE_[i] = ItemImage.objects.filter(ii_i = i)
    return {
        'article' : _ARTICLE_, 
        'article_image' : _ARTICLE_IMAGE_ , 
        'question' : _QUESTION_,
        'question_image' : _QUESTION_IMAGE_,
        'item' : _ITEM_,
        'item_image' : _ITEM_IMAGE_
    }
```

and I wrote index.html for template like this:

```
<div class = "content-a">
        <div class = "article">
            {%for article in articles%}
                <span>{{article.a_con}}</span>
                {%for article_image in article_images%}
                    <img src = {{article_image.src}}>
                {%endfor%}
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
        {%for question in questions %}
            <div class = "question">
                <span>{{question.q_con}}</span>
                {%for question_image in question_images %}
                    <img src = {{question_image.src}}>
                {%endfor%}
                {%for item in items[question] %}
                <div class = "item">
                    <span>{{item.i_con}}</span>
                    {%for item_image in item_images%}
                        <img src = {{item_image[item].src}}>
                    {%endfor%}
                </div>
                {%endfor%}
            </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

Of course, It doesn't work ...
In this case, how can I make it work ? 
If you have any idea please help me ... this problem is bothering me during a week ...

EDIT:

the result shows this error page.

[image]

Comment: if You need to change rest of selectors content based on firs article selection then you need to use Ajax in template to return rendered context from DB.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi thanks for reply, Do you mean if I use Ajax I can display multiple 'for loop' in my page?

Comment: you can change context displayed in question section based on selected article.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Ah understood, thank you If I need I should consider using that

Comment: please share what error do you get?

Comment: @bdemirka sure! I will do it tomorrow

Comment: @bdemirka the error is 'TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '[question]' from 'items[question]' ' do you know about it?

Comment: dıd you try items.question ınstead of items[question]

Comment: @bdemirka I did, It doesn't show error page anymore but doesn't display any items

Comment: @bdemirka I solved this problem refer 
 this topic thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable

Answer (score -1):

To begin with, you may have a look at your syntax. You're making a repeated mistake at the functions calls such as:

```
{%for article in article%} instead of {% for article in article %}
{%for question_image in question_images %} instead of  {% for  
{%endfor%} instead of {% endfor %}
```

Correct them and try again. It might work.
For such a case, you may have a look at the correct tag format in the official `django` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language).

Comment: I already leave my seat ... I'll check tomorrow and I'm gonna tell you about the result! thank you!

Comment: it is not a syntax error, you can use it both way

Comment: @bedemirka. If what you say is correct is new for me. I just check the official django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language. You will see that what I'm proposing is the correct syntax, and in my experience I messed up whenever I format the tags as you 're proposing.

Comment: thank you, but It shows same error after fix it.