# can't access dictionary item using integer keys in django templates

Tags: python, dictionary, django-templates

```
dict = {1:'a','1':'b'}
```

`{{1}}` or `{{'1'}}` should give `'a'` and `'b'` respectively but it's not working in any case.
is it valid or should use only alphabets for keys?

because I want to make multiplication table for entered number in textbox like for 2

```
2 x 1 = 2 
2 x 2 = 4 
.
.
.

2 x 9 =18
2 x 10 = 20
```

Comment: Can you post the whole template portion of how you're trying to use this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick [google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable) reveals that to access

```
mydict = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
```

you must do

```
{{ mydict.key1 }}, {{ mydict.key2 }}
```

So to access the key 1, you would do:

```
{{dict.1}}
```

Note that using the dict as your variable name shadows the keyword dict and is something you should avoid.