# How to access nested fields in JSONField in the HTML template (Django)

Tags: json, django

I have a `user` model with a field called `data` containing nested data, e.g for one `user` that could be

```
data = {
      "2020":{"payment_date":"today","amount":600},
      "2021":{"payment_date":"","amount":800}
        }
```

the model also has a `name` field.

In my HTML I can access `name` and `data` but I struggle getting "deeper" into `data` to extract `amount` from `2020` and `2021`.

I would assume I could do `{{user.data.2020}}` but that does not work. Doing `{{user.data}}` does indeed show the "remaining data".

Right now I have tried

```
<div class="media-body">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>2020</th>
            <th>2021</th>
        </tr>
        {% for user in users%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>  # works
            <td>{{user.data.2020.amount}}</td> 
            <td>{{user.data.2021.amount}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
</div>
```

but that does not work

Comment: Does it help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another idea you can also use [custom templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) instead of a loop:

*templatetags/dictionary_item.py*

```
import json
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def dictionary_item(dic, itm):
    try:
        return dic.get(itm)
    except AttributeError:
        return json.loads(dic).get(itm)
```

And in your template:

```
{% load dictionary_item %}

<div class="media-body">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>2020</th>
            <th>2021</th>
        </tr>
        {% for user in users%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>  # works
            <td>{{user.data|dictionary_item:"2020"|dictionary_item:"amount"}}</td> 
            <td>{{user.data|dictionary_item:"2021"|dictionary_item:"amount"}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works great! I had to tweak it a bit, since the first instance is (for some reason) a string thus we have to convert `dic` to a dictionary using `json.loads`. Note, afterwards is it a dictionary, thus make it a `try:  return dic.get(itm) ` and catch the `AttributeError` and use `return json.loads(dic).get(itm)`

Comment: If you would like you could add that try/catch to the answer.