# How do I render individual dynamic elements from a dictionary in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

This is my first question (sorry for any english mistakes), and I appreciate your help in advance! I'm working with a Django app (MVT). I have a view that returns a dictionary, and I would like to access individual elements of the dictionary in the template. However, in the template, I can render the complete dictionary without any issues, but I can't render individual elements. I'll show you the view that return the dict registros_por_dia.

```
class GrillaView(View):
    template_name = 'grilla.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def contar_registros(self, fecha):
       ... 

    def post(self, request, fecha=None):
        if fecha:
        ...
        else:
            # Esta parte se ejecutará cuando se envíe el formulario del mes y año
            mes = int(request.POST.get('mes'))
            ano = int(request.POST.get('ano'))
            
            dias_en_mes = [dia for dia in range(1, monthrange(ano, mes)[1] + 1)]
            registros_por_dia = {}

            for dia in dias_en_mes:
                fecha = datetime(ano, mes, dia).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                contador = self.contar_registros(fecha)
                registros_por_dia[dia] = contador
         
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'dias_en_mes': dias_en_mes, 'registros_por_dia': registros_por_dia})
```

And now I'll show you the relevant part of the template.

```
...
{% if dias_en_mes %}
    {% with fecha_format='%Y-%m-%d' %}
    <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

        {% for dia in dias_en_mes %}
        {% with fecha=dia|date:fecha_format %}
        <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px;">
            <span>{{ dia }}</span>
            <br>
            <span>{{registros_por_dia.dia}}</span>
            
        </div>
        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

The line {{registros_por_dia.dia}} doesn't render any value. However, if I change it to {{registros_por_dia}}, it does render the entire dictionary.
I've tried various variants without success.

- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|get:dia}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia.get(dia, 'Valor predeterminado')}}</span>`
- `{% with registro=registros_por_dia.dia %}<span>{{ registro }}</span>              {% endwith %}`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|getattr:dia}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia[dia]}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|dictlookup:dia}}</span>`

None of them works, does anyone know what I can do?
Thank you very much!

I've tried various variants without success.

- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|get:dia}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia.get(dia, 'Valor predeterminado')}}</span>`
- `{% with registro=registros_por_dia.dia %}<span>{{ registro }}</span>              {% endwith %}`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|getattr:dia}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia[dia]}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|dictlookup:dia}}</span>`

None of them works, does anyone know what I can do?
Thank you very much!

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason `{{registros_por_dia.dia}}` doesn't work is that the template sees it as `registros_por_dia["dia"]` rather than `registros_por_dia[dia]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for the dictionary's `items` method:

```
{% for dia, contador in registros_por_dia.items %}

{{dia}}: {{contador}}<br />

{% endfor %}
```

Then of course if `contador` is a datatype like a list, treat that like follows within the outer loop:

```
{% for dia, contador in registros_por_dia.items %}

{{dia}}: {% for c in contador %} {{c}} {% endfor %}<br />

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The problem is that i can access to each value of dias_en_mes (from 1 to 31) on each box, but i can´t do the same with registros_por_dia. All i can do is to access to the complete dict of registros_por_dia. I want to render individual values of registro_por_dia.
It´s melting my brain. Here i put some images

1) This is what happens when `<span>{{registros_por_dia.dia}}</span>`
2) This is when `<span>{{registros_por_dia}}</span>`

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQxk1.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBlK4.png

Comment: @EstudioSAG Okay, I follow you. You're trying to dynamically pass the value of `dia` as the dictionary key in your for loop within the template.  Django's template language doesn't support this out of the box, so you need to write a small template filter as demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/2052575 Also [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) shows what you need to do to enable this (create `templatetags/__init__.py` and `templatetags/my_filters.py` where this code belongs) then `{% load my_filters %}` in your template prior to using.

Comment: @EstudioSAG You were almost there with `{{registros_por_dia|dictlookup:dia}}`. you just need to implement that `dictlookup` method yourself, (or `get_item` as demonstrated in the answer I just linked) :-)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This problem had me stuck for one week. I'm a beginner in this, but a determined one! With your guidance, I could solve it. I can't describe how happy I am!! Thanks!