# Can not access the values of dictionary using jinja

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Here is my views.py

```
def following(request):
    currentUser = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    currentUser_followings = Following_System.objects.get(user=currentUser).following
    allPosts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp").reverse()
    followingPosts = []
    for user in currentUser_followings.all():
        for post in allPosts:
            if post.author == user:
                followingPosts.append(post)
    
    **post_likers_ids = {post.id: list(post.likers.values_list('id', flat=True)) for post in followingPosts}**

    # Show 10 posts per page.
    paginator = Paginator(followingPosts, 5) 
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, "network/following.html",{
        "page_obj": page_obj,
        "post_likers_ids" : post_likers_ids
    })
```

I debug, and the post_likers_ids return: **({4: [2], 2: [1,3,5]})**
And now in my following html why the if condition is always false (Although it should be true for some, cause I know the expected input output):

```
        {% for post in page_obj %}
        <div class="list-group-item">
            {% with post_id=post.id %}
                {% if user.id in post_likers_ids.post_id %}
                  <p>The user liked this </p>
                {% else %}
                  <p>The user have not liked this </p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Here is my model if that helps:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="author")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likers = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="liked_posts", blank=True)

    def serialize(self):
        likes_count = self.likers.count()  #
        likers = [user.id for user in self.likers.all()]
        
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "content": self.content,
            "author": self.author.username,
            "author_id": self.author.id,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
            "likes": likes_count,
            "likers" : likers,
        }
class Following_System(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    following = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="following")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"User {self.user} is following {', '.join([user.username for user in self.following.all()])}"
```

It seems like using the jinja template, the

```
post_likers_ids.post_id
```

behave weirdly, for example, when post_id = 4; using

```
post_likers_ids.4
```

return the correct value, but using post_likers_ids.post_id returns empty

Comment: Can you share your `Following_system`? We can boost efficiency by making better use of this.

Comment: yes, i updated on the post

Answer (score 2):

You probably check this with:

```
{% if user.id in post_likers_ids[post_id] %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endif %}
```

But building such dictionary itself is not efficient, since it will trigger *n* queries for *n* posts.

We can boost efficiency by working with a JOIN to determine the authors we are following, and furthermore by letting the database determine if the post was liked, with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


def following(request):
    followingPosts = (
        Post.objects.filter(author__following__user=request.user)
        .order_by('-timestamp')
        .annotate(
            is_liked=Exists(
                Post.likers.through.objects.filter(
                    user=request.user, post_id=OuterRef('pk')
                )
            )
        )
        .distinct()
    )

    # Show 10 posts per page.
    paginator = Paginator(followingPosts, 5)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(
        request,
        'network/following.html',
        {
            'page_obj': page_obj,
        },
    )
```

Then in the template, we get:

```
{% for post in page_obj %}
    <!-- … -->
    {% if post.liked %}
        <!-- … -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I try that, but get the error: "Could not parse the remainder: '[post_id]' from 'post_likers_ids[post_id]'"

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn: then you are not using jinja, but Django's template engine. Jinja extended the syntax to allow subscripting.

Comment: i see, how could I fixed that?

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn: by altering the `TEMPLATES` setting with `BACKEND` pointing to `'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2'`

Comment: Can I modify it to django template? replacing to jinja2 says: " A 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates' instance must be configured in TEMPLATES in order to use the admin application."

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn: you can add a second one for the admin templates: https://www.webforefront.com/django/jinjaconfiguration.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256831/discussion-between-khoa-nguyn-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here, it is a work-around:
[Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable)

Comment: Please *don't*: it is inefficient, and also moves business logic to the template, which is the main reason Django does not implement it in the first place. Moreover if it fails, it fails silently, which is often *not* a good idea.